# Is this the best way to access array elements using non-constant index in GLSL 1.0?

Tags: glsl, webgl

I need to be writing against 1.0 spec so I can run on WebGL 1.0 as well.
I came up with the following helper function.

Q1: Is this the best that can be done? Are there more creative ways? (note: At the time of compiling the source I have the total length of the uniform and I can inject that into the source. However when writing the logic I won't know exactly what I'm dealing with so I can't use vec4 or things like that)

Q2: If instead of using uniform arrays, I used textures what would the efficiency be in creating textures for sizes of say 1-10? And then accessing the elements using texture2D() calls?

```
precision mediump float;
varying vec4 vColor;
uniform float alpha[5];
float getItem(float[5] a, int index) {
    for(int i=0; i<5;i++) {
        if(i==index) return a[i];
    }
}
void main(void) {
    float c = getItem(alpha, i+1);
    gl_FragColor = vColor;
}
```

Comment: yet another example of why you should use a texture.  `float elem = texture2D(arrayTexture, vec2((.5 + index) / textureWidth, 0)).r;`

Comment: Would textures be OK for really small sizes like 1 to 10? I will gladly create them since they overall simplify my code everywhere

Answer (score 0):

According to the spec, GLSL ES v1.0 should support dynamic indexing of uniform arrays. Why not use `array[index]` to sample the uniform?

Regarding the textures, if the size of your data is small, it is not so efficient as using uniforms, especially if you need to change the data during runtime operation of your app.

Comment: Not sure if that really works. Just did this simple test in Firefox and there's an error telling me that the "Index expression must be constant": `    precision mediump float;
    uniform float M[4];
    varying vec4 vColor;

    void main(void) {
        int i = 1;
        float k = M[i*2];
        gl_FragColor = vColor;
    }`

Comment: Yep, because the index includes multiplication. It is possible to rewrite your code without the need to use it.